# Вернуться к или на?

Tags: предлоги

Вернуться к внутренней лабораторий/ на внутреннюю лабораторию/ в внутреннюю лабораторию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о возвращении внутрь помещения лаборатории, то:

> Вернуться **во** внутреннюю лабораторию.

(**"во"** - это вариант предлога **"в"** перед словом, начинающимся на "в")

Если же речь идет о том, чтобы просто вернуться к лаборатории, на заходя в нее (например, чтобы встретиться с кем-то у входа), то:

> Вернуться **к** внутренней лаборатории.